# Restrict Google Forms to 2 types of email

Tags: google-forms

I'd like to restrict my respondants to provide one of those email domains:

a gmail account or a hotmail.ca

Do I need to use a script to resolve my problem or just use the validation option ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by using the regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(gmail.com|hotmail.ca)$
```